# How to examine appsync cache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-cli, serverless, aws-appsync

I am having issues with cached requests in appsync. We use graphql and some non-unique requests are returning data for other requests.

All I need is to simply be able to examine the cache itself but it does not seem to exist in either CloudFront or Elasticache.

Is there a way to examine the cache itself so I can understand why these separate requests are returning the same data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to read AppSync cache entries. The [cache-related API actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) are: `CreateApiCache`, `DeleteApiCache`, `FlushApiCache` (all), `GetApiCache` (settings), `UpdateApiCache` (settings).